# Instantiate a class at runtime through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Hello I am trying to discover and instantiate a class at run time. The Assembly is loaded in factory object.

It works fine till this point

```
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(
   (factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations")));
```

but I can not get property name with `obj` as `Obj.FirstName` or `obj.LastName` is not available so I am trying to typecast it to a proper underlying class.

But the below given code does not work.

```
 factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations")
     .UnderlyingSystemType.BaseType a = 
         Activator.CreateInstance(factory.ProxyAssembly
              .GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations").UnderlyingSystemType);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cant you cast the obj to Authorizations? What exactly are you trying to do, because there might be other, better ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: I am running it in Immediate window so far.  factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations").UnderlyingSystemType.BaseType a = Activator.CreateInstance(factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations").UnderlyingSystemType);
End of expression expected  It shows the message "End of expression expected"

Comment: @TJHeuvel I don't know about the type Authorizations. I found it by  factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations").UnderlyingSystemType

Comment: So here is the detail  @TJHeuvel, I am creating an assembly for webservice proxy based on wsdl file at runtime. I am using codedom provider. Web service method has parameter type 'Authorizations'. So after creating the assembly 1. I want to discover the parameter type 2. Instantiate it. 3. Assign values and send the assigned parameter to webservice proxy.  and  I don't know about the type Authorizations. I found it by  factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations").UnderlyingSystemType

Comment: @Reflection newbie, It doesn't sound like you need a strongly typed object for this.  It will have its type even if it is an `object`. You could just pass it to whatever method receives it using reflection.

Comment: Thanks smartcaveman, my other requirement is to assign the value like Obj.FirstName or obj.LastName. But these property are not available until I make the object strongly typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast, you don't have the assembly added as a reference in your project.  You need to use Reflection to get the object properties.  Use Type.GetProperty and PropertyInfo.GetValue.  Note how the C# version 4 *dynamic* keyword can lessen the syntax pain considerably, recommended.

Comment: Thanks Hans It worked with p = obj.GetProperty and p.SetValue().

Answer (score 1):

```
tempuri.org.Authorizations a =  (tempuri.org.Authorizations)Activator.CreateInstance(factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.or g.Authorizations");
```

Look into casting with (**Type**).  Where **Type** is class type that comes back.  Type is a compile time thing in that case.  Reflection uses abstractions to shield the concrete type, but in that case you would need it.  Unless you use do:

```
a.getClass().getField("FirstName").getString(a);
```

Comment: Hi Justin, I getting this type tempuri.org.Authorizations from Assembly. I don't know the type yet, just name. So I can't use `tempuri.org.Authorizations a'. That is why I am using factory.ProxyAssembly.GetType("tempuri.org.Authorizations")
     .UnderlyingSystemType.BaseType a on left side of assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object after instantiating it.

Comment: thanks guys. I am not yet able to find a way to typecast to a dynamic runtime type.